# What does the :300 mean for this google font?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a font loading in my HTML from a web template:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

What does the ":300" mean and do?

Comment: Quite puzzling that the Google Fonts [Getting Started page](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) makes no mention of selecting the numerical font weight, e.g. by appending `:300` to the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It primarly sets the `font-weight` for the CSS that is generated. But it also changes the source font-family also.

Ex.

- 300 - Open Sans Light
- 600 - Open Sans Semibold
- 800 - Open Sans Extrabold

Compare your link vs http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800

Answer (score 2):

#### Font-weight may be defined as:

- **normal**

Normal font weight. Same as 400.

- **bold**

Bold font weight. Same as 700.

- **lighter**

One font weight lighter than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).

- **bolder**

One font weight darker than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).

---

#### Or it can be defined with a numeric representation:

- **100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900**

Numeric font weights for fonts that provide more than just normal and bold.

If the exact weight given is unavailable, then 600-900 use the closest available darker weight (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter weight), and 100-500 use the closest available lighter weight (or, if there is none, the closest available darker weight).

This means that for fonts that provide only normal and bold, 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold.

---

To that particular case, the font is being set a bit lighter then the normal boldness.

Answer (score 0):

It's a font weight. 300 is normal weight.

It's in CSS2: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/css/quickref/css_fontweight.html